# How can I exclude database.yml from a git repo while still being able to push to dotCloud?

Tags: git, dotcloud

I want to add a remote git collaborator on one of my projects, but I do not want to have him access my passwords in database.yml.  I know how to .gitignore database.yml and purge the repo accordingly, but the trouble is I am deploying this particular project to DotCloud, which, as far as I know, requires the database.yml to be part of the git repo.  The best solution I can think of now is using rsync to push to DotCloud, but I'd rather push directly from the git repo.  Anyone know of a way I can do this?

Comment: I have no idea what DotCloud is, but I find it hard to believe that any platform would require you to put passwords in a git repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a couple of different options depending on what you want to do.

You can put the `database.yml` file in your `.gitignore file`, and then when using dotcloud push use rsync instead of git to push your code.

```
$ dotcloud push --all ramen
```

Using the `--all` option will force the uploader to use the “rsync” method, and therefore push all your files. See this page for more info. http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/git-hg/#pushing-uncomitted-changes

If you need to ignore files then you can create a `.dotcloudignore` file, and add the files you want to ignore with the push there.

The second, better approach is to not put your passwords in your `database.yml` file at all. Add your passwords as environment variables, and then your `database.yml` file can be safe and free of passwords.

```
$ dotcloud var set myapp MYVAR=MYVALUE
```

You can then reference the variables the same way as you do with `environment.yml` or `environment.json` . More info can be found here: http://docs.dotcloud.com/guides/environment/#adding-environment-variables

Answer (score 0):

NOTE 1: Suppose the simpler way is to create alias in git that would automatically execute rsync:

```
git config alias.<yourcommand>; !<your script>
```

Example:

```
git config alias.sendtocloud "! echo 'rsync' && rsync && echo pull && git pull"
```

and later try:

```
git sendtocloud <continue parameters as after git pull >
```

If you want to have pure git solution and at least 3 repos:

- [Y]our: (database.yml not important?)
- [C]ollaborator: (without database.yml)
- [D]otCloud (with original databse.yml)

So there are additional questions:

1. How do you share repository with your collaborator? (pull or push and by who?)
2. OR do you have some bare repository to exchange data (shared by [Y] and [C])?
3. Is that correct, that you don't need to have database.yml in your repo?

NOTE 2: you can use git hooks to do almost everything what you want. For example you can even manage with some temporary branches before update etc.

NOTE 3: If you don't need database.yml in your repo than you can create in-middle bare repo before [y] and [D] with "update" hook to forward changes to [D]